# Are there alternative ways to catch potentially missed signals with condition variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Consider the following simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool cv_flag = false; // I'm talking about this flag here

void startThread1()
{
    std::cout << "thread 1 prints first\n";
    {
        // Set the flag (lock to be safe)
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        cv_flag = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
}

void startThread2()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    if (!cv_flag)
    {
        cv.wait(lock);
    }

    std::cout << "thread 2 prints second\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread1(startThread1);
    std::thread thread2(startThread2);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

Here, `cv_flag` is used to make sure that thread 2 does not lock and `wait()` if thread 1 has already sent the notification with `notify_one()`. Without it, thread 2 might lock and `wait()` *after* thread 1 has already called `notify_one()`, resulting in an indefinite hang since thread 2 is waiting for something that's already happened.

I've seen lots of code like this where something like `cv_flag` is used solely to detect potentially missed notifications.

Is this really the only way to do this? And the cleanest and simplest? I think it would be great if you could do something like:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
// no more need for cv_flag

void startThread1()
{
    std::cout << "thread 1 prints first\n";
    cv.notify_one();
}

void startThread2()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    cv.wait_unless_already_notified(lock); // Unfortunately, this function doesn't exist

    std::cout << "thread 2 prints second\n";
}
```

Is there anything like `wait_unless_already_notified()`? If not, is there a technical reason for it not existing?

*Edit*: changed *signal/signaled* references to *notify/notified/notification* to disambiguate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `cv_flag` is used solely to detect potentially missed signals.

Your information is incomplete. The flag's primary function is not **solely** to detect missed notifications (which is not the same as a signal, see Dietmar's comments), but mainly to protect against spurious wake ups of the `condition_variable` (in other words, `cv.wait()` can return even if no one called one of the `cv.notify_*()` functions). Speaking of which, your example code is wrong:

```
if (!cv_flag)
{
    cv.wait(lock);
}
```

It should be a `while` loop:

```
while (!cv_flag)
{
    cv.wait(lock);
}
```

> Is there anything like `wait_unless_already_signaled()`? If not, is there a technical reason for it not existing?

Because of the possible spurious wake ups already mentioned, it is **necessary** to have a separate variable that reflects the "real" event's state, at the very least a boolean flag, so that you can resume waiting if the `condition_variable` woke up spuriously (hence the `while` loop instead of a mere `if`). And of course this requirement makes your proposed `wait_unless_already_signaled()` useless, which explains why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Out of curiosity, given the confined problem of the OP's posted code, what source can trip a "spurious" set of the cv *without* a notify or broadcast? I completely concur with the mantra that one needs to ensure their predicate is set *after* wake up, particularly in a broadcast environment, but what is it about this *specific* sample that dictates the need to protect from it?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure about this, but I strongly suspect this has to do with Unix signals. The POSIX API has a number of such idiosyncrasies (eg. requiring one to test for `EINTR` errors in client code instead of putting such tests/restarts in the API itself) which exist out of historical reasons -- the *worse is better* principle.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The term _signal_ used in the original question should have used _notification_ as coming from `notify_one()` or `notify_all()`. Because a signal, e.g., sent using `pthread_kill()` could cause a spurious wake-up. There is also an implementation reason which makes it inefficient to disallow spurious wake-ups.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Good catch regarding "signal" vs "notification", this could indeed lead to confusion. I fixed the wording.

Comment: @DietmarKühl again, in the confines of the question code, how so? I understand very well the incestuous marriage of cv's with their mutex and predicate data, though I freely admit a lack of familiarity with waking a cv-wait via pthread_kill? is there a specific example you have in mind (I can always google it, just curious if you already had one for reference).

Comment: I changed "signal" to "notification", sorry for the ambiguity. For some reason I thought std condition variables didn't have spurious wake-ups like pthreads did, but you're completely right about them.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the implementation is free to cause a spurious wake-up. Whether or not my code is likely to on a particular system is one thing, but it's simply not guaranteed by the standard to not have a spurious wake-up.

Comment: @Cornstalks Certainly so. 'Tis the reason I always validate the predicate after a wakeup (the defensive posture always at the ready, if you will). As you should, since you do, after all, own the mutex that protects it in the first place. It was the organization of the code that made be wonder, that is all. I concur they can happen, just not by *your* hand in this specific sample.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ah, I see. Yes, I agree.

Comment: @WhozCraig: In the end, `std::condition_variable` will use something like the pthread condition variable under the hood and having a signal delivered to a thread will wake-up the thread. While the thread is woken up it would miss the notification, if any, however, i.e., the condition needs to be reevaluated before going to sleep but the condition variable doesn't know what the condition is (unless the predicate version of `wait()` is used).

Comment: @syam And winding all the way back to your first *comment* in this chain, that certainly makes sense. Just thought you saw something I didn't. Your answer is certainly accurate. (+1)

Answer (score 7):

A condition variable is not used to detect a signal! The purpose of a condition variable is to wait until one or more threads have completed something which can be detected as not being complete, yet. The signal is merely an indication that another thread has changed something and the waiting thread should reevaluate the condition it is waiting on. Aside from the signal sent to the condition variable, something else needs to be changed to wait on. If you want to detect if another thread has just sent some signal, you'll need the other thread to set up a corresponding indication.

Please note, that your code is, however, problematic: `wait()` doesn't necessarily wake up because of a signal being sent. It can wake up due to spurious wake-ups without another thread ever signalling it. That is, you need to always use `wait()` with a reevaluation of a condition, e.g.:

1. `while (!cv_flag) { cv.wait(lock); }`
2. `cv.wait(lock, [&](){ return cv_flag; });`